# svg figures hidden in jupyterlab after some time

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I recently found I could make all my matplotlib figures with SVG by default in my jupyterlab notebooks with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']
```

However, if I refresh the page, the figures disappear, leaving behind

```
<Figure size 864x576 with 1 Axes>
```

This effect does not occur without changing the inline backend. My plotly figures also still show up after a refresh. I would prefer not to have to re-run the cells. Looking at the actual ipynb file, the SVG is right there in the actual file. How can I get this figure to show without re-running the cell?

Comment: Hi, JupyterLab co-maintainer here. This is not my experience with SVG outputs in JupyterLab and I cannot reproduce this behaviour in the latest pre-release (JupyterLab 3.1.0rc1). What browser and version of JupyterLab are you using? There were some changes in Chromium which broke things but those might be already fixed; we also have a workaround in 3.0.15+ and 3.1 (release candidate phase). I would love to hear more details from you.

Comment: Note: this indeed happens with untrusted notebooks (the answerof @saaj is correct) but the thing is that your own notebooks should be trusted by default. I indeed found an issue showing that sometimes there are issues with this: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9765 and there is a related discussion on  https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-not-remembering-trust-for-notebooks/7869.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour looks in line with the [security model of Jupyter](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#our-security-model).

> - Untrusted HTML is always sanitized
> - Untrusted Javascript is never executed
> - HTML and Javascript in Markdown cells are never trusted
> - Outputs generated by the user are trusted
> - Any other HTML or Javascript (in Markdown cells, output generated by others) is never trusted
> - The central question of trust is “Did the current user do this?”

Because SVG can have `<script>` tags, there's an attack surface. Hence, you have two options to display the SVG:

1. Re-run the cell that generates an SVG (last point above).
2. [Explicitly trust](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#explicit-trust) the notebook, `jupyter trust /path/to/notebook.ipynb`.

Notes:

1. Plotly saves `image/png` version in the output of the cell. It's displayed when the notebook is loaded. But the loaded (not reran) cell also has interactivity. Not sure how that exemption works.
2. As a side note, current JupyterLab's behaviour varies with different forms of SVG display (see [issue#10464](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10464)), but that's not the issue here.

Comment: Note: you can also mark notebooks as trusted from within JupyterLab using Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in JupyterLab 3.0+).

Comment: This solution worked. I noticed I need to trust the notebook again after restarting jupyter. Will I need to trust it each time I start up jupyter?

Comment: It seems so as it works the same for me. I took a quick look. [`NotebookNotary.sign`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/blob/373d9261/nbformat/sign.py#L444) just saves HMAC SHA256 of the notebook contents in the SQLite database at `$HOME/.local/share/jupyter/nbsignatures.db`. `nbsignatures` table has `path` column but it's always `NULL`, and specifically when a new recrord is added by `jupyter trust`.